# Disable trigger hangs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to do this from an ASP.NET web app:

```
Alter Table Contacts Disable Trigger All 
-- Do some stuff
Alter Table Contacts Enable Trigger All
```

In some situations the `Disable Trigger` statement hangs. Where should I start looking to figure out what's causing this? If I restart SQL server it goes back to behaving normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the Activity Monitor from SSMS to see *why* it blocks. Or you can look into `blocking_session_id` column is [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx).

My guess: schema changes require a schema modification lock on the table. Any operation (like SELECT, UPDATE etc) will place a schema stability lock on the table, blocking any ALTER until the SELECT completes. So the Disable Trigger ALTER is blcoked by all the pending table access (SELECT) statement.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I used SQL Profiler to see what was going on and you were absolutely right. FWIW: The code above was inside a loop through a LINQ to SQL IEnumerable. If I execute the query first and get the results (with .ToList) and then loop through the list, everything is fine.